# Question about subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Now that the semester is over I am going over a few things in my abstract algebra book and there is this one example that I never fully understood.  It is example 40 (page 45) from "Abstract Algebra, theory and applications" by Thomas W. Judson. The book is open source so here is the [link.](http://abstract.ups.edu/)

The part I get hung up on is, "Other than the trivial subgroup and the group itself, the group $\mathbb{Z}_4$ has a single subgroup consisting of the elements $0$ and $2$.  What about a subgroup consisting of $\{0,1,2\}$ or $\{0,2,3\}$?  What am I missing?

Comment: $1+2=3\not\in \{0,1,2\}$, $2+3=1\not\in\{0,2,3\}$. These are not subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: A subgroup must be closed under the group operation: first case 1+2=3 is not in the set, second case 2+3=...

Comment: I see. I knew it was something I was overlooking.

Comment: You're forgetting about closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a subgroup of $\mathbb Z_4$ contains $1$, then it contains $2=1+1$, $3=2+1$, and $0=3+1$. So it is all of $\mathbb Z_4$.

If it contains $3$, it contains $2=3+3$, $1=3+2$, and $0=2+2$.

So a proper subgroup can only contain $0$ and $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Those are certainly *subsets*, but they do not form groups with the operation inherited from $\Bbb Z_4$, so they are not *subgroups*.

Answer (score 0):

A subgroup is a subset which is also a group. That means it is a non-empty set of elements closed under the group operation and containing the inverse of every element.

If all the elements have finite order, then closure under the group operation ensures that their inverses are present*. I have stated "non-empty" because the existence of an element and its inverse means that closure ensures that the identity is there.

*Writing the group additively if $na=0$ then $(n-1)a+a=0$ and $(n-1)a$ is the inverse of $a$.

As an example of a set closed under the group operation which isn't a subgroup, take the positive integers as a subset of the integers with addition as the group operation.

In your examples the inverse of $1$ is $3$ and vice versa, so you need neither of them or both of them in any subgroup.